# How to pause while the media scanner is running

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

I have an application that shows, plays and delete videos. I want to know that how to pause the current thread or processing while the media scanner is running. it takes about 4 to 7 seconds for media scanner to complete its activity..

any suggestions

Comment: Few things to mention here. The scanner time depends on sd card capacity - if you have 16gb of media files the scanner wont finish in 4+7 seconds. What exactly is your questoin how to pouse the current thread or process or how to determine if the media scannere is running ?

Comment: Actually I want to perform an action only after the media scanner has finished media scanning..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you just need to implement the [OnScanCompletedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener.html).

If not, add some code to clarify your question.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use it.. I just want to perform an operation once the media scanning is completed.. can you please show me how to use OnScanCompletedListener..

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to know when the media scanner is done you have to register [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) which will listen for [ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED). [Here](http://www.slideshare.net/CodeAndroid/android-intent-intent-filter-broadcast-receivers) is good presentation that gives good explanation of [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), [IntentFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html) and [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:)

```
while(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
                System.out.println("wait sdcard mount.");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Not a great idea.. this code by itself will lock up your device for 5 seconds, and there is no guarantee that the process will be finished at that time.

Comment: yes. my mistake)). This piece was a test. At the time I thought it was a good idea. But then I rethought it.